# trying to make night/day mode buttons by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As I wrote on the title, I'm trying to make night/day mode on html by JS.
Why doesn't it work? and what should I change to make it work?
Both button doesn't work.
Here's my code.

```
</html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Marcel Duchamp</title>
        <style>
          .js{
            font-weight:bold;
            color:red;
          }
          #first{
            font-weight:bold;
          }
          p{text-indent:15px;}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body style="background-color:#FFD7AD;">
        <h1 style="color:#FF5733;margin-left:5px;">Marcel Duchamp</h1>
        <h2 style="background-color:orange;color:coral;padding:10px">France to USA</h2>
        <p>
          about Marcel Duchamp
        </p>
          <input type="button" value="Night" onclick="
            document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = #686868;
            document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';
          ">
          <input type="button" value="Day" onclick="
            document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try using the `script` tag, put your code in that, then use a function call. This is sometimes considered better practice as it declutter your HTML code.

Comment: It would help if you provide ways you tried to find the problem. Otherwise it is another "solve my problem" question that is of little use to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a typo error, **Not** `onlcick`, **It's** `onclick`. And you missed a `''` to your colour code `#686868`, It will break your `inline JS`.

**Working Code is here**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Marcel Duchamp</title>
  <style>
    .js {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }
    
    #first {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    p {
      text-indent: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFD7AD;">
  <h1 style="color:#FF5733;margin-left:5px;">Marcel Duchamp</h1>
  <h2 style="background-color:orange;color:coral;padding:10px">France to USA</h2>
  <p>
    about Marcel Duchamp
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Night" onclick="
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#686868';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';"/>
  <input type="button" value="Day" onclick="
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';"/>
</body>
</html>
```

> **NOTE : Please avoid lengthy inline JS**